# Are reciprocal lattice basis vectors parallel to their corresponding real lattice basis vectors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, fourier-transform, crystals

So I had a question asking to find the angle between b* and (113) plane normal in a tetragonal unit cell. I know that the angle between two plane normals are given by:

[image]

My thinking was that if I know a direction that is parallel to b*. I could put that direction to the formula and calculate the angle.

I know that b*.b = 1
So my questions is if this means b* and b are parallel to each other and if I use [010] direction, will I make a mistake?

I also read from De Graeg, *Structure of Materials* that:
[image]

So this had me confused, are the reciprocal lattice basis vectors parallel to their corresponding real lattice basis vectors, perpendicular or neither of the two?

Comment: What is b* in your problem? A specific reciprocal lattice vector or a general one? I mean, why would you think b* is parallel to [010]? If b* is given, why not use its own direction?

Answer (score 2):

> are the reciprocal lattice basis vectors parallel to their corresponding
> real lattice basis vectors, perpendicular or neither of the two?

No, in general they are neither.

Let $\mathbf{b}_1$, $\mathbf{b}_2$, $\mathbf{b}_3$ be the basis vectors of the real lattice,
and $\mathbf{b}^*_1$, $\mathbf{b}^*_2$, $\mathbf{b}^*_3$ the basis vectors of the reciprocal lattice.

According to *[Reciprocal lattice - Three dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice#Three_dimensions)* they are related by:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{b}^*_1&=\frac{2\pi}{V}\mathbf{b}_2\times\mathbf{b}_3 \\
\mathbf{b}^*_2&=\frac{2\pi}{V}\mathbf{b}_3\times\mathbf{b}_1 \\
\mathbf{b}^*_3&=\frac{2\pi}{V}\mathbf{b}_1\times\mathbf{b}_2
\end{align}$$

From the properties of the $\times$ product, it is clear that

- $\mathbf{b}^*_1$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}_2$ and $\mathbf{b}_3$,
- $\mathbf{b}^*_2$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}_3$ and $\mathbf{b}_1$,
- $\mathbf{b}^*_3$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}_1$ and $\mathbf{b}_2$.

However, this usually does not mean that $\mathbf{b}^*_i$ is parallel to $\mathbf{b}_i$.
And it certainly doesn't mean $\mathbf{b}^*_i$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{b}_i$.
This can already be seen in two dimensions.

[image: basis vectors]

It is also not hard to convince yourself about the same fact in three dimensions.
(But it is harder to draw, and therefore I didn't bother with that.)

Comment: I get it now, so b* should be perpendicular to the plane oa and oc makes. o being origin. But then what does b*b = 1 mean?

Comment: @mnalb447 It is the [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the vectors  $\mathbf{b}^*$ and $\mathbf{b}$

Comment: Doesn't dot product being equal to 1 mean the vectors are parallel? That is what got me confused.

Comment: @mnalb447 No, it doesn't mean that. See the section "Geometric definition" in the link of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

> The reciprocal lattice vector **g** with components (h,k,l) is
> perpendicular to the plane with Miller index (hkl).

Yes.

Suppose $3$ non orthogonal vectors **a**, **b** and **c**, like $3$ lines from one of the vertex of a tetrahedron. Each $2$ of them determine a plane. In a bravais lattice, this is a cristallographic plane, with a long range symmetry. The cross product of these vectors generates a new vector perpendicular to this plane. And perpendicular to each of those vectors. If we define for example:$$\mathbf G_1 = \frac{\mathbf a \times \mathbf b}{(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) \mathbf {.c}} \implies \mathbf G_1 \mathbf{.c} = 1\; \mathbf G_1 \mathbf{.b} = \mathbf G_1 \mathbf{.a} = 0$$